# Cordova jQuery Ajax is cutting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I currently working with Cordova and try to upload data with following code:

```
var data = { 'track': JSON.stringify(tt.track), 'uuid': device.uuid, 'name': obj.name, 'org': obj.org, 'name': obj.name + ' ' + obj.fistname };
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/savingscript.php",
  type: "post",
  data: data,
  dataType: 'text',
  cache: false,
  success: function (d) {
    if (d == "OK") {
      alert("fine")
    } else {
      alert(d)
    }
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

Problem is, that last posted data was cut in the middle of the firstname.
Example: data has property "name" = "John McCarter", but Serverscript receives: "John McC".

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

I'm using Cordova with NuGet-Package jquery-2.2.3.min.js on VisualStudio Community 2015

Comment: Does it happens for every variable, or from the name variable going forward?

Comment: issue doesn't seem to be from this side. could be from server.

Comment: Allways last item was cut, if i send same data from a website, everything is fine. A var_dump($_REQUEST) shows a string(8) for the name var

Comment: I tested some variations and find out, that lat and lon inside the track was also cut to a size of 13, Other vars are posted without any missing chars

Comment: If i put the name to the first item of the data-object of the $.ajax the name was transmitted correctly.

Comment: Switching type to "get", transfers the data correctly, but with "Get" i had a maximum data limit,so i have to use post. Any ideas?